# Is there a pattern of increased aggression/violent behaviors in hotter climates? Scientific Research? Mixed reviews

Tags: geography, environmental-climate, air-temperature, social-anthropology, violent-behavior

I've heard it several times before that hotter climates regions of the world often have more individuals that exhibit more aggression and violent behavior than colder climates do (that is not to say that colder climates don't have violent people, but that it is more prevalent in hotter climates because the heat causes an arousal). However, I've been reading mixed reviews. And I'm a bit skeptical if that is biased research....

The CNN article I read addressed the arguments for it and against it, and I'm wondering if there is a scholarly article that is more convincing and comes down on either side of the argument? http://www.cnn.com/2016/07/07/health/climate-violence/

Answer (score -1):

I've never found any scientific evidence to back me up but I always thought hot weather predisposes people to violence.  However, it may be that during the very cold months of winter people tend to be indoors most of the time and outdoor interaction and sports are less frequent. Anyway, it would be interesting to check the statistics of violence reports in the northern US states in January and in July and compare them. That might tell us something.